# Can I get the "onCycleEnd" event for AltBeacon Android SDK

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I'm using the AltBeacon library in my app, and only running the scan every few minutes, whether foreground or background. I would really like to know when the scan has completed, though, as I also want to occasionally scan for non-LE Bluetooth devices. I see that there is an event called "onCycleEnd", which seems like what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how (or if) I can get to it to handle when that event fires.

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the cycle ends, the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` fires.  You should be able to trigger any necessary logic on that callback.

Comment: That seems like the iOS SDK solution - is there a way to do something similar in the Android SDK? I know there's an event called "onCycleEnd", but it's a member of BeaconService (I think), which I don't think I have access to via the BeaconManager.

Comment: Sorry, just realized my previous comment is wrong - didRangeBeaconsInRegion is not an iOS SDK thing, it's in the Android SDK that way as well. However, does that indicate that the scan is completed? In other words, if I try to start a BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() based on didRangeBeaconsInRegion, will the adapter be available to do a scan?

I guess I will have to just try it and see - I'll update with my findings.

Comment: We may be talking past eachother here... You can certainly call `BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery()`  at any time and it will start a "classic" bluetooth scan to find non-LE devices.   I don't think there is any reason you  need to make sure this isn't going on at the same time as the Bluetooth LE scans.  But to clarify the way the Android Beacon Library works in the foreground, once it stops one LE scan, it immediately starts the next.  In the background it pauses between scans on older OS versions and maintains one long lower power scan on newer OS versions.

Comment: Interesting - I am under the (perhaps misguided) belief that the BT Adapter cannot be in discovery for classic and LE devices simultaneously, but I will try it out and see. Side question, though - on the newer OS version's "one long lower power scan", that would, I presume, include the callbacks to NonBeaconLeScanCallback for such devices it finds. If such devices are nearby, I assume that means it would be "discovering" those constantly - is that also "low power"? Does constant discovery of that sort of device hurt battery life?

Comment: Good question.  The low power scan uses a filter to look only for advertisements that match a certain prefix used to find a beacon, and if one is matched, it exits the low power scan mode and returns to normal scanning mode.  If this happens in the background, the normal scans are spaced out at 10 seconds every 5 minutes.  Bottom line:  the low power can is not useful for non-beacon detections.

Comment: Seems I've been wrong (for quite some time) about being able to do classic scans and BLE scans in parallel. Seems I can do both at the same time. Interesting.